# distinctUnionOfObjects case insensitive

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, unique

I have an array of NSDictionary. Each array item has a key named "Name". Now I want to remove duplicate entries based on this name value.

This work perfectly:

```
aMyArray = [aMyArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Name"];
```

The problem are that result array still contains duplicates string, based on the case.  Ex:  [@"Franck", "franck"]

How can I remove these duplicate?

Thanks

Comment: What about applying `-lowercaseString` or `capitalizedString` or `uppercaseString` before filtering out the duplicates elements?

Comment: Because I need the case to be kept.  (for the duplicate, I don't care which one will be removed)

Comment: Ok, if you don't care you can always make a copy of the array and retrieve the "original" object by an UUID. If it's too expensive,  you can use always an `NSSet`  instead of an `NSArray` and override `-isEqual` and `-hash` of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this

```
// in your class implementation 
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    typeof(self) obj = (typeof(self))object;
    return ([self.Name caseInsensitiveCompare:obj.Name] == NSOrderedSame);
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [[self.Name lowercaseString] hash];
}

// and then 
NSSet *distinctObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSArray *result = distinctObjects.allObjects;
```

Alternatively you could customise this *KVC collection operator* by swizzling `valueForKeyPath:` to parse your custom `DSL`, possibly winding up with something like

```
aMyArray = [aMyArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects[caseInsensitive].Name"];
```

which doesn't seem to be a good idea for me, but it certainly a viable solution to your problem.

Comment: Your `-hash` method is not valid for the given `-isEqual:` method. The rule is that, if `-isEqual:` considers two objects equal, then the `-hash` method **must** give the same hash value for both. If the two names differ by case, `-[NSString hash]` is likely to give different hashes, but your `-isEqual:` method will call them equal.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to normalise `Name`s before getting their hashes. Thanks